# Backup via mysqldump. Is this safe to do on production or will it crash the server?

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

I want to run this command during the time in which the production server is running the application:

```
mysqldump -u sbp -p databasename_production > databasename_development_copy.sql
```

Is this safe to do while production is running or no?

In short, development would be a lot easier if I had a copy of production data. Is this safe to do?

I'm doing this in digitalocean fwiw.

Answer (score 10):

Unless you add `--single-transaction` and you're using innodb tables this could block writes to the database for the period of the dump. So use `--single-transaction` (and innodb).

The only risk is if you are using a DO instance that is far too small and causes the mysql server or mysqldump (less likely) to run out of memory.

If you start gaining swap usage during the dump you can kill off the mysqldump process.

These few cases aside, its pretty safe.

Comment: Why would that single transaction flag prevent this from blocking writes?

Comment: why would that help?

Comment: [mysqldump](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mysqldump): 'because then it dumps the consistent state of the database at the time when BEGIN was issued without blocking any applications

Comment: Mysqldump uses the --opt flag by default, which sets a "read lock" - meaning it puts all tables into read-only mode. This is the safest way to ensure dumped data is "consistent". However, it means all write queries to the database are delayed (waiting) for the lock to be released - this *will* affect your application. The single-transaction flag instead uses a transaction, avoiding a read-lock. The data within the transaction will be consistent as a transaction creates a "snapshot" of the data when the 1st query is made within the transaction (see: Repeatable Read isolation level).